# Airflow Webserver Shutting down

Tags: webserver, airflow, gunicorn

my airflow webserver shut down abruptly around the same timing about 16:37 GMT.
My airflow scheduler runs fine (no crash) tasks still run.

There is not much error except.

```
Handling signal: ttou
Worker exiting (pid: 118711)
ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
ERROR - Shutting down webserver
Handling signal: term
Worker exiting
Worker exiting
Worker exiting
Worker exiting
Worker exiting
Shutting down: Master
```

Is it a cause of memory?
My cfg setting for webserver is standard.

```
# Number of seconds the webserver waits before killing gunicorn master that doesn't respond
web_server_master_timeout = 120

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 30
```

Update:
Ok its doesn't crash everyday but today I have gunicorn unable to restart log.

```
ERROR - [0/0] Some workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected
```

Update: 30 October 2020

> [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:108237)

I am getting this, I have increased timeout to 240, twice the default value.

Anyone know why this keep arising?

Comment: How are your running this ? where is airflow meatadata DB ? Is your webserver able to connect to that. Please check that kindly.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon,
In the cfg file. 
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@localhost:5432/airflow

airflow.db is in the same directory as where I execute and run airflow with the cfg file. 

Sorry if am unclear.